# What is the role of the person escorting and recording the driver during the interview?

Tags: formula-1

In the formula 1 after the race finish and they interviewing the driver, they are escorted by a person recording the interview.

What is that role position? And why they need it?

Are they afraid of what driver say? Or they need a copy of the interview in case the press put something different?

Shouldn't be easy just let the driver use the same microphone wear during the race

[image]

Comment: The title and question don't match at all, and both seem based on a false premise. Your personal comment on the appearance and stature of the person holding the recorder are irrelevant and sexist. Cars have drivers, not pilots.

Comment: @Nij I remove the comment, Sorry english isnt my first lenguaje. my question is why they need someone to record the interview, looks like they try to keep them in a leash? So they arent really free to express during interviews.

Comment: Why do you think, in the first place, that this is either a limit on the driver or that the recording is evidence for anything? Drivers and teams have their own websites and articles and sponsors to think about, of course they want their own copies of any interview.

Comment: @nij, because they could just use a wireless microphone, you know like they use to talk during the race. No need to have someone behind.

Comment: Please downvoters would you mind comment on why you think this is a bad question?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza person escorting them are PR minder and would make it easy to search for answer but answer still would be opiniated.

Comment: Thanks @RamchandraGiri , Google for `F1 PR minder` give me some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ram chandra point it out. The person is a PR minder. So doesnt only record the interview, also help them to navigate between all the reporter and sponsors. And also act like an assistant so driver only have to worry about racing.

I google `F1 PR Minder` and find this post in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/formula1/comments/23ln8z/what_is_the_actual_job_of_the_drivers_minders/)

One interesting comment here:

> Ted Kravitz did a piece on this with Vettel's minder.
>
> Their jobs are far more than just simply recording stuff the driver's say, they're basically like a personal assistant.
>
> Drivers (top ones anyway) have a lot of obligations, especially with media and sponsors, if they're not out on the track racing, they're most likely doing an interview or making an appearance with sponsors. The PAs arrange their schedules, from daily activities down to the very minute (eg, 15 minutes spent doing signings before needing to go to A, B and C), they try to fit as many activities in as possible and their trips are planned down to the minutes.
>
> Apart from that, the paperwork involved in getting an F1 driver around the world is insane, the coordination and scheduling is a huge task and one of the most important jobs these "minders" have.
>
> As an example, to satisfy anti-doping laws the drivers must submit a schedule of where they'll be a year in advance so the WADA (world anti-doping agency) knows exactly where they are at any given time, this allows them to do random spot-checks with no warning. The penalty for them not finding you can be a ban/loss of super license. [**Example**](http://www.stuff.co.nz/sport/motorsport/8390177/Drug-testers-raid-Formula-One-drivers) of how stringent the WADA are at doing spot checks You can imagine just doing that one specific time tabling task would be a huge headache.

Also they show one example of why is important record the interview:

> They make their own recording of all the interviews, so that when some journalist misquotes a driver for a story, they can play their copy of the tape to prove what was actually said.
> Happened just a few weeks ago, someone reported that Hamilton said he "blew away" Nico ... every other "journalist" lazily copied and pasted this story without checking ... Mercedes issued their recording with Hamilton saying he "pulled away".

Answer (score -2):

I've wondered the same thing but I think it might be in order to verify press later. That is to say, have a way of confirming or denying what a driver may have said during a post-race interview. It seems similar to what some politicians have used in past.